# pytest, collect all tests name before running test

Tags: python, pytest

in my project, I wish to collect all test nodes name before running any test so that I can create folders based on the test node name for dumping data generated from the tests.

I know that I can get the name in test function with `reqeust.node.name`. But instead of doing `os.makedirs` I wish to have a single fixture that handle its. e.g.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autorun=True)
def make_test_folders(all_test_nodes):
    for node in all_test_nodes:
       os.makedirs(f'somepath/{node.name}')
```

Can you suggest how this can be done ?

Remark: This is not for clean up purposes, but I actually will need those results, in this case audio files, for posthoc analysis and archiving.

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't use tmp or a TmpDir (with the tempfile buitin library)? It is the common way to create folders and files in running time when testing. With this approach you don't have to care about removing the files when the tests ends

Comment: I do use a tmp folder. But I also want to organize each test case's result inside of that tmp folder. Because I actually want to analyze those results (audio files) in case test failed

Comment: if you use a Linux system the tmp folder is not deleted instant so you can still check the results

Comment: I don't think you understand what I meant, sorry. In the tests, each test case will generate some audio files, and I would like to organize those files based on certain folder structure. It has nothing to do with tmp folder or not. That part is not the purpose but only how those files should be organized. Because of the large quantity, instead of dumping everything in one folder, I would like to create a folder structure based on test case name.

Comment: Why not include `tmp_path` fixture to the test function and when invoking pytest `pytest --basetemp=./somedir` ?

Answer (score 1):

I found this post:
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/discussions/2039#discussioncomment-85524
And credit to https://github.com/nicoddemus. The way this user proposed is to make a plugin that does the collection beforehand. My adaptation looks like this:

```
class TestCollection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.collected = []

    def pytest_collection_modifyitems(self, items):
        for item in items:
            self.collected.append(item.nodeid)


@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def make_test_outputs_folders():
    coll = TestCollection()
    directory = sys.argv[1]
    pytest.main(['--collect-only', directory], plugins=[coll])
    for case in coll.collected:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join('tmp', case.replace("::", ".")), exist_ok=True)
```